# Fundamental MVC - Editing model content from another controller

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, model-view-controller

I'm attempting to understand some basic fundamentals when it comes to the Rails way and the MVC design pattern.

Let's say I'm building a CMS. I have the following:

```
/Pages
controller
model
view
```

When a request comes through, it should check for results based on the URL in the `Pages` controller, and present the page.

Now, let's say I have a backend for this, simply put, an admin section:

```
Admin
controller - index, edit actions
view
```

Now, the admin section authenticates through a `Users` model, so it shouldn't have its own model (at least I don't see the need currently). Users should be able to edit content to/from the `Pages` model. Is this something that needs to be explicitly stated? Is it something that I render at the controller level, or should it be made using an AJAX call to the controller? I'm having a hard time grasping how exactly this process works.

Besides being able to edit Pages, I'd have a similar issue with editing something like a Blog model, so it would be awesome to get some insight on how this is accomplished.

Edit: Or am I overcomplicating because they're using the same (extended) class?

Answer (score 0):

I use Devise for user authentication. The Devise wiki on github has a page on how to add a simple admin role to your user profile. Or you can use CanCan for a complete authorization model. Either way, there are helper methods provided for checking a user's role.

In the case of a CMS where you want to have a read only and an editable view of the same content, I think I would simply use an is_admin? condition in controller actions such as new, create, edit, update, destroy. Regular users would only have access to index and show.

You can use an "admin" namespace in your routes (check the Rails Guides on routing) and then put all those admin actions into one controller, leave index and show in the base controller, and then user a before_filter in your admin controller to keep the code a little cleaner.

The views templates can also use and is_admin? (or similar) helper method to expose certain functionality/links etc.

Comment: Thanks for the insight. I think I have a grasp on the concept, but one thing I'm not sure on is something like the is_admin? condition - that is determined by the Users model, no? How do other controllers access that model? Is it magic? :)